# No error but app not working. Button not working

Tags: android, compiler-errors

I am new to android studio and I am making a app which uses gps and ant to show in textview with lat long values my app is running completely its asking for permissions to but when I click on button to get lat long values it show nothing in textview i am not able to find error please help me out.

```
package com.example.gpps;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.core.app.ActivityCompat;
import androidx.core.content.ContextCompat;

import android.Manifest;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.location.Address;
import android.location.Geocoder;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Locale;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements LocationListener {

    Button getLocationBtn;
    TextView locationText;
    private LocationManager locationManager;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        getLocationBtn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.getLocationBtn);
        locationText = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.locationText);


        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getApplicationContext(),
                android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED &&
                ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getApplicationContext(),
                        android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION)
                        != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                    new String[]{android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION,
                            android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION}, 101);

        }


        getLocationBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                getLocation();
            }
        });
    }

    void getLocation() {
        try {
            locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
            locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 5000, 5, this);
        }
        catch(SecurityException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        locationText.setText("Latitude: " + location.getLatitude() + "\n Longitude: " + location.getLongitude());


        try{
            Geocoder geocoder =new Geocoder(this,Locale.getDefault());
            List<Address> addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(location.getLatitude(),location.getLongitude(),1);
            locationText.setText(locationText.getText()+ " \n" +addresses.get(0).getAddressLine(0) + "," + addresses.get(0).getAddressLine(1)

            + addresses.get(0).getAddressLine(2));
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Please Enable GPS and Internet", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {

    }
}
\



Manifest file
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.gpps">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>


    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>

build.gradel file

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
    buildToolsVersion "29.0.0"
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/services/javax.annotation.processing.Processor'
        defaultConfig {
            applicationId "com.example.gpps"
            minSdkVersion 19
            targetSdkVersion 29
            versionCode 1
            versionName "1.0"
            testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        }
        buildTypes {
            release {
                minifyEnabled false
                proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            }
        }
    }

    dependencies {
        implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
        implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.2'
        implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
        testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
        androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.2.0'
        androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

is you getLocation fucntion goes into catch block?